# Users in private teams lose their Enthusiast badge (and possibly others) after being deactivated and re-activated

Tags: bug, badges, stack-overflow-for-teams

I spent 30 days trying to get my Enthusiast badge, and I lost it after my team account was deactivated and then re-activated.  When the team account is reactivated, it seems that badges are removed but come back when the system auto-detects that you've in fact earned them.  However this is not true for the Enthusiast badge (and I'd assume not for the Fanatic badge either, which would be a *huge* loss!).  This method is unreliable and results in loss of badges.